# How can I *predictably* mark changed cells in AG-Grid React?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, cellrenderer

I have a functional component in React that uses the AG-grid component, that looks roughly like this:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react'

export default function FormEditor(props) {

  .... code for fetching data etc. goes here ...

  // create ref to be able to call ag-grid.api on our spreadsheet
  const editFormRef = useRef()

  // can we log the row data to the console? Yes!
  function logData() {
    if (!editFormRef.current.api) {
      return
    }
    const rowCount = editFormRef.current.api.getDisplayedRowCount()
    for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      const rowNode = editFormRef.current.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(i)
      console.log(`row ${i + 1} -> `, rowNode.data)
      // Perform your logic
    }
  }

  // will the data that's changed be highlighted? Maybe, on the second go...
  function markCellChanged(params) {
    if (!editFormRef.current.api) {
      return
    }
    const row = editFormRef.current.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(params.rowIndex)
    console.log('markCellChanged() called ')
    if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
      params.colDef.cellStyle = function(params) {
        return { backgroundColor: '#6fcc44', transparency: 0.5 }
      }
      console.log('Redrawing row ', row)
      editFormRef.current.api.redrawRows({ rowNodes: [row] })
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AgGridReact
        ref={editFormRef}
        rowSelection="multiple"
        columnDefs={columns}
        rowData={rows}
        rowDragManaged={true}
        components={{ editCellEditor: ReviewCellEditor }}
        // editType="fullRow"
        enableFillHandle={true}
      />
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => logData()}>
        Log Data
      </Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

The issue is that it does work, but only on the second go. And it also works, if a cell in that column has already been edited.

This is not the final position I want to be in, as I want to check the data against the original rows supplied, not just the last value changed in a cell. I just thought it was best to start small, and build ;-)

Can anyone explain this behaviour, and let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "on the second go" ?

Comment: I mean, I change the value -> no change in background colour. I change the value again (or back to the original value) -> background changes colour.

Comment: I had a similar kind of issue with different useCase. I don't remember how exactly i solves it but did you tried deltaRowDataMode=true ?

Comment: Nope, sadly it had no effect.

Comment: If you are using your own custom renderer, try to use the default one and see if it still has the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ag-grid in Angular, not React, but it seems to me that you shouldn't be changing the columnDef's cellStyle, as that *should* apply to the entire column.

If you want to change the style just for the one cell, AFAIK, the proper way to do it is to provide a dictionary of functions for colDef.cellClassRules. The keys are css class names, and the values are functions that take a cell value and return a boolean indicating whether the class should be applied to the cell, as in:

```
cellClassRules: {
    // apply green to 2008
    'rag-green-outer': function(params) { return params.value === 2008},
    // apply amber 2004
    'rag-amber-outer': function(params) { return params.value === 2004},
    // apply red to 2000
    'rag-red-outer': function(params) { return params.value === 2000}
}
```

See the documentation at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/#cell-class-rules

Comment: I did see that, but couldn't see how to get at the previous value of the cell :-(